# 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found error on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Though I have included the necessary .dylib files I get the following error on Xcode:

> 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found

[image: Error indication]

Comment: Did you set the build (and library) search path?

Comment: Yes. I added them.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when setting up my first OpenCV C++ project in Xcode, following these instructions: https://medium.com/@jaskaranvirdi/setting-up-opencv-and-c-development-environment-in-xcode-b6027728003

What fixed it was to set the *Header Search Path* and *Library Search Path* to *recursive* and maybe it helped to set the *Framework search path* to /usr/local/lib (and *recursive*) and *Always Search User Paths* to *Yes*.

In Xcode, double click the search path to set them to recursive.
[Set Header Search Path and Library Search Path to recursive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICUHE.png)

Comment: I did the same set up as the Medium Link. Still it didn't work. After setting Header Search Path and Library Search Path to recursive, worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have the correct OpenCV version installed. In my case only v2 worked.

I first uninstalled all opencv versions:

```
$ brew uninstall opencv@2
$ brew uninstall opencv@3
$ brew uninstall opencv@4
```

and installed v2 with:

```
$ brew install opencv@2
```

Reinstalling could have worked, but I didn't test it. Something broke with my previous installation when I migrated to Catalina.

I then used the following flags when compiling (you may need different flags):

```
-I/usr/local/opt/opencv@2/include -L/usr/local/opt/opencv@2/lib -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```